# Is it possible to report uid from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am collecting data using Google's Measurement Protocol, and sending the uid parameter. This works fine. But I would like to be able to fetch the uid back from Google. I can fetch the value of a custom dimension, but I would prefer not to set cd1 = uid for every request if possible.

I notice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461439/google-analytics-how-to-get-the-client-id-anonymous-client-id-sent-with-meas) that there is a comment by [@DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) saying that it is not possible... and I suspect he's right, but I'd like to hear from someone who knows for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to get the uid without setting it through a custom dimension.

Comment: I don't believe it, either, (it's not in the interface, nor in the query explorer etc.), I just have no idea what level of evidence the OP expects. Plus hadn't Google fouled up by calling this "User ID"  (which somehow makes people think that this identifies users) instead of "Cross Device Tracking Id" (which is what User id really is) people would probably not even ask this question.

Comment: I guess I just want something a bit more comprehensive than "I don't believe it's possible", which is where I was in the first place. I admit that it's hard to know quite what would satisfy me, short of either:
- someone proving me wrong, or
- someone from Google answering.
But I will continue with our shared assumption for now.

Comment: @ChrisLear, I understand your trouble, but "does this undocumentend feature that no one has ever heard of exist" is simply not  an answerable question, especially if you are not prepared to take the word of rather experienced people (daimto is a Google Certifed Analytics developer).  We can hardly expect Google to produce lists of features that not exists.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, Yes, I also agree with you about the misconception that the UID is to track a unique user, but the key benefit is cross-platform/device tracking.

Comment: @eikePierstorff Thanks for pointing out daimto's credentials. That's good enough for me. I should have noticed, obviously. I'm going to accept nyuen's answer.